# Проблема с подключением Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase

Проблема такова: 
есть небольшой проект, я подключаю к нему Firebase по инструкции.
В JS-файл добавляю все нужные строки, предварительно установив `Firebase`:

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import {initializeApp} from "firebase/app";
import {getAnalytics} from "firebase/analytics"
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "88888888",
  authDomain: "distance-ea18b.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "distance-ea18b",
  storageBucket: "distance-ea18b.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "606739653445",
  appId: "1:606739653445:web:f5dbba23bf0b43c53bd42c",
  measurementId: "G-5D5FQE79XD"
};
console.log(firebase);

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
```

А тип подключаемого скрипта меняю на "module":

```
<script type="module" src="js/main.js" defer></script>
```

После этих махинаций в консоли появляется ошибка:

```
TypeError: 
Module specifier, 'firebase/app' does not start with "/", "./", or "../". 
Referenced from http://127.0.0.1:5500/js/main.js
```

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как это исправить

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66644782/uncaught-typeerror-failed-to-resolve-module-specifier-firebase-app-relative